# How would you describe an aggressive guy who tends to fight people most of the time in AmE?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request, american-english

What do you call someone who is an aggressive guy who is always making some kind of trouble which usually leads to a fight? Such a guy tends to turn a small issue into a fight. I found two terms and I was wondering if someone could let me know which one works here in a natural way:

> - He is a trouble.
> - He is a hell-on-wheels.

For me they both work properly, but I didn't find any reference showing that "trouble" works in this sense. [Urban dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=hell%20on%20wheels) and some other sources somehow refer to the meaning in my question, though not completely.

I would appreciate it if they do not work properly here, someone could let me know what native speakers would call such a person in AmE.

**Added:** what I need is an AmE informal term.

Comment: I would call him a *hot head*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your two suggestions:

> - He is a trouble.
> - He is a hell-on-wheels.

is that we do **not** use an indefinite article when using these terms. Instead, we could say:

> - He is trouble.
> - He is hell on wheels.

or maybe:

> - He is nothing but trouble.

If you wanted to use a noun with an indefinite article, we might say:

> - He is a **troublemaker**.

---

Incidentally, “hell on wheels” is an idiom, so the term needn’t be hyphenated. Also, I’m not sure it fits exactly what you describe in your question. Yes, it is used to describe a person or situation that is difficult to handle, but it doesn’t necessarily imply an argumentative spirit.

Comment: Adding to that, a *trouble-stirrer* (or depending on how crude one wants to be, a *shit-stirrer*) are terms often used to describe exactly this type of person - a person go goes around and actively tries to turn everything into an argument or fight.

Answer (score 4):

Well, there's probably a few choice words people might call a person like this, but that's a separate discussion. :)

With regards to your two suggestions, you do not want the "a" in either of them, they should be:

> He is trouble.
>
> He is hell-on-wheels.

Here are some other suggestions for adjectives you could use:

> argumentative
>
> confrontational
>
> combative
>
> belligerent

Also, with regards to turning something insignificant/small into a big deal, some people would say:

> He makes a mountain out of a mole hill.

Although this may be more idiomatic to UK English rather than AmE - there's a Wikipedia page on it [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Make_a_mountain_out_of_a_molehill), or you can Google it for some more background information.

Comment: *Mountain out of a molehill* is common in the US as well. Good suggestion.

Comment: @J.R. great, thanks for confirming that, I wasn't sure as I couldn't remember ever hearing it when I'm been in the US, good to know.

Comment: Not at all! Making a mountain out of a mole hill is used mostly when someone makes a small thing bigger that it is to make it bold or somehow emphasize on it. It doesn't fit what I'm looking for at all. Meanwhile, I need an AmE informal term to describe such a person. (Added to my question.)

Comment: Also *"he makes mountains out of mole hills"*.

Comment: @AdrianHHH sure, or "He tends to make mountains out of mole hills", "He always makes mountains out of mole hills". I think the problem is the OP is looking for something more directly relating to the person's aggression, rather than just their tendency to exaggerate a situation, although I've absolutely used (and heard used) the mountain-mole hill phrase used to describe just such a person, although sometimes the true subtext can only be determined by spoken tone/inflections, so if the OP is looking for a succinct written term, it's probably not the most appropriate.

Comment: @A-friend - The kind of aggressive people you are talking about _**do**_ make mountains out of molehills. Sure, there are _other_ ways to make mountains out of molehills, too, but it is an excellent suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

He's a "rabble rouser" if he gets other people involved in his fights. He's "explosive" if little things enrage him.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The adjective for someone who is quick to fight is

> pugnacious

It has the same root as

> pugilist = boxer, one who fights with his hands